# The instance member 'currentComponentConfiguration' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple code snippet:

```
class CreateNewViewPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final ComponentConfiguration currentComponentConfiguration = ComponentConfiguration(1, 1);
  final Components components = Components(currentComponentConfiguration);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CreateNewViewPage();
}
```

Unfortunately, when I want to send `currentComponentConfiguration` to the `Components` class construct, I get the following information: `The instance member 'currentComponentConfiguration' can't be accessed in an initializer.`

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a non-static variable for initialzing another non-static variable. Either make `currentComponentConfiguration` a static member or do `components` object creation in `State` class (`_CreateNewViewPageState`).

**Using Static**

```
class CreateNewViewPage extends StatefulWidget {

  static final ComponentConfiguration currentComponentConfiguration = ComponentConfiguration(1, 1);
  final Components components = Components(currentComponentConfiguration);

  @override
  _CreateNewViewPageState createState() => _CreateNewViewPageState();
}
```

**Using State class**

```
class CreateNewViewPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final ComponentConfiguration currentComponentConfiguration = ComponentConfiguration(1, 1);

  @override
  _CreateNewViewPageState createState() => _CreateNewViewPageState();
}

class _CreateNewViewPageState extends State<CreateNewViewPage> {
  Components components;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    components = Components(widget.currentComponentConfiguration);
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Hello, World!', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4);
  }
}
```